# "He was introduced (to) essay structure."

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, passive-voice

I introduced essay structure to him

Which passive sentence is correct and why?

> He was introduced to essay structure.
>
> He was introduced essay structure.

Answer (score 0):

> I introduced essay structure to him.

I see two options for the passive voice.  The simpler option promotes the direct object to the subject position:

> Essay structure was introduced [to him] [by me].

Both "to him" and "by me" are optional prepositional phrases.  The clause "essay structure was introduced" on its own is grammatically complete.  The passive voice statement does not have a direct object.

The other option is one of your suggestions:

> He was introduced [to essay structure] [by me].

Again, the passive voice statement does not have a direct object.  The prepositional phrases are not required by the grammar of the statement.

The error in your other option is that it's trying to use a direct object that the verb phrase does not allow:

> * He was introduced essay structure.

Some passive-voice verb structures do allow a direct object.  These are *ditransitive* verbs.  In the active voice, these verbs can take two objects, one indirect and one direct.  Either one can be promoted to the subject of a passive-voice clause.  When the subject of the passive voice clause is the same as the *indirect* object of the active, the passive verb structure still allows a direct object.

> I gave him a gift.   -- active
>   A gift was given to him.   -- passive; promotion of the direct object, the indirect object becomes an optional prepositional phrase
>   He was given a gift.   -- passive; promotion of the indirect object, the direct object is not changed

Indirect objects represent semantic *recipients* or *beneficiaries*.  In my example above, the preposition "him" is the recipient of the gift.  Even though the verb *to introduce* does not allow an indirect object, its semantics allow a recipient.  More than allowed, it is often expected.  Furthermore, the direct object and the recipient are generally reciprocal:

> I introduced essay structure to him.
>   I introduced him to essay structure.

This is the reason that we seem to be able to promote a mere prepositional phrase to the subject position of a passive-voice clause.  These two clauses mean nearly the same thing, despite the obvious grammatical difference between them.  The same applies to the two passive-voice transformations:

> I introduced essay structure to him. / Essay structure was introduced to him.
>
> I introduced him to essay structure. / He was introduced to essay structure.

Both passive-voice versions work.  Neither passive voice version allows a direct object.